# Expected value of function of minimum between two random variables

Tags: probability, random-variables, expectation

Two independent random variable $X,Y$ are distributed on $[0,\infty)$ according to the cumulative distribution function $F(x)=1-(x+1)^{-2}$. Let $Z=\min(X,Y)$. Determine $E\left[\frac{Z}{Z+2}\right].$

By definition of expectation, we have $E\left[\frac{Z}{Z+2}\right]=\int_0^\infty\frac{z}{z+2}f(z)dz$, where $f(z)$ is the distribution function of $Z$. The distribution function of $X$ can be found by taking the derivative of $1-(x+1)^{-2}$, which gives $2(x+1)^{-3}$, but how can we find the distribution function of $Z$?

Comment: Hint: $Z > c$ if and only if $X > c$ and $Y > c$. Take complements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By definition:

$$\begin{align}
F_Z(z) & = \mathsf P(\min \{X,Y\}\leq z) 
\\[1ex] &= 1-\mathsf P(\min\{X,Y\}>z) 
\\[1ex] &= 1-\mathsf P(X>z)\mathsf P(Y>z) 
\\[1ex] & = 1-(1-F(z))^2
\\[1ex] & = 1 - (z+1)^{-4}
\end{align}$$

You can take it from here.